# Make a mosaic image (bitmap format)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, image-processing, bitmap, mosaic

I want to make a mosaic photo with different window-size (that has been determined by user). This is just like a first draft of the code but I have problems to get the pixels and calculating averages. Then put the avarage value in each pixel and continue to the end. Even I get error to converting them of diffrent types: (Also the other part manufacturers a gray-scale image)
p.s: sorry that I am in the very first steps of learning image processing.

```
''' void CImageProcessingDoc::OnProcessMosaic()
{
if (m_pImage) {
    DlgMosaicOption dlg;

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK) {

        DWORD dwWindowSize = dlg.m_dwWindowSize;

        DWORD width = m_pImage->GetWidth();
        DWORD height = m_pImage->GetHeight();

        RGBQUAD color;
        RGBQUAD newcolor;
        float X_step = width / dwWindowSize;
        float Y_step = height / dwWindowSize;
        int avg, pixel;
        for (DWORD y = 0; y < dwWindowSize; y++) {
            for (DWORD x = 0; x < dwWindowSize; x++) {
                color = m_pImage->GetPixelColor(x, y);
                (RGBQUAD) pixel =  m_pImage->GetPixelColor(x, y);
                avR += (int)(color.red(pixel);
                avG += (int)(color.green(pixel);
                avB += (int)(color.blue(pixel);
                newcolor.rgbBlue  = (BYTE)RGB2GRAY(color.rgbRed, color.rgbGreen, color.rgbBlue);
                newcolor.rgbGreen = (BYTE)RGB2GRAY(color.rgbRed, color.rgbGreen, color.rgbBlue);
                newcolor.rgbRed   = (BYTE)RGB2GRAY(color.rgbRed, color.rgbGreen, color.rgbBlue);

                m_pImage->SetPixelColor(x, y, newcolor);
            }
        }
    }
}
 } '''
```

Could anyone please help me to understand the problem?

Comment: You must initialize your variables, otherwise their initial values can be anything. As a result you get incorrect results. E.g. `int avg = 0; int pixel = 0;`

Comment: @vahancho Clearly good advise but not the problem here

Comment: Please provide some more information. What do you expect and what is the result of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing up spatial, spectral and temporal average here.

### Spatial average

This is the operation of computing average of pixels over an area.

You have to compute `eR = 1/N * (P0.R + P1.R + P2.R + P3.R + ...)`, `eG = 1/N * (P0.G + P1.G + ...)`, `eB = 1/N * (P0.B + P1.B + ...)`

You'll get a pixel with as many color as there was in the input picture, but with limited spatial frequency, a picture computed like this will appear blurred, with no details

### Spectral average

This is the operation of computing average of the components (spectrum) of each pixels.

You have to compute `e = 1/3 * (P0.R + P0.G + P0.B)`

You'll get a monochromic picture with the exact same spatial frequency as the initial picture.

### Temporal average

While you haven't talked about it, this is for reference. The idea is to compute the average of each pixel, and each component for N pictures in a temporal sequence

This gives a kind of motion blurred picture.

### Answer

If I understand your question correctly, you want spectral average to convert a RGB to the average grey value taken that `grey = (R+G+B)/3`.

Thus, you pixel loop should look like this:

```
for (DWORD y = 0; y < dwWindowSize; y++) {
            for (DWORD x = 0; x < dwWindowSize; x++) {
                color = m_pImage->GetPixelColor(x, y);
                float avg = (color.rgbRed + color.rgbGreen + color.rgbBlue) / 3.f;
                m_pImage->SetPixelColor(x, y, RGBQUAD(avg, avg, avg, 1.0f));
            }
        }
```

Please notice that converting non linear RGB (usually called sRGB) to luminance using the average is a poor formula for RGB to grayscale conversion. You should read about RGB to Lab* conversion (you are interested in `L` part only) or at least RGB to YUV (you are interested to `Y` part only).

If your question is about resizing the input picture, then you are not using the appropriate algorithm, what you want is called **resampling**.